# Autocmd with a python file not working

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-python

I'm using the regular Vim that comes with Ubuntu.

I have the following line of code in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd filetype py nnoremap <F10> :w <bar> !python3 %<CR>
```

It's not working, although I have a similar setup with `<F10>` for cpp files.

Comment: The name of the FileType is actually `python` and not `py`. Can you try that and see if it's all that's needed to solve your issue?

Comment: Should probably be a `<buffer>` mapping

Answer (score 3):

The correct FileType is "python" and not "py". You can check for that by opening a Python file in Vim and checking the detected FileType with the `:set ft?` command, which I'd expect will return the following:

```
:set ft?
  filetype=python
```

If you create a mapping for a specific filetype (such as "python" in your case), make sure you create a [local mapping](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-local) using `<buffer>`. Otherwise the mapping will be global and will work on every buffer and not only those with Python source files.

If you use an `autocmd` in your vimrc, make sure you wrap it in an [`augroup`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aaugroup) to prevent getting duplicated commands if you reload your vimrc.

Putting it all together:

```
augroup vimrc_python
  au!
  au FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F10> :w <bar> !python3 %<CR>
augroup END
```

Alternatively, you can add filetype mappings for Python in a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` (or `python_*.vim`, or `python/*.vim`, inside that `ftplugin` directory), which gets automatically loaded by Vim whenever a file of type Python is loaded. (That way you don't need to use explicit `autocmd`s, Vim will take care of those details on your behalf.)

If you use that approach, all you need inside that file to create this mapping is:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F10> :w <bar> !python3 %<CR>
```

Comment: What's the question mark in `:set ft?` for, isn't the same as `:set ft`?

Comment: @Jon For boolean options (such as `et`, short for `expandtab`, or `ai` for `autoindent`) if you don't use the `?` at the end you will *set* the option instead of query whether it's set. Yes, for something like `ft` it doesn't matter, but in general using the `?` to query is never really incorrect and in many cases it's required, so I find it better to always include it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!